# Save two objects in a single VF page using custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I am in the process of developing an apex:form that will save two records: Recipient__c and Scholarship_Award__c.

I need to create a custom controller to save new records for both objects on the same VF page.
The trouble is the Recipient__c record will need to be saved first following the insertion of Scholarship_Award__c because it references Recipient__c as the parent in a master-detail relationship.

Ideally, the end-user will input the fields of recipient__c, and scholarship_award__c and two records will be saved: a new recipient, and a new scholarship with that recipient as the parent.

How can I go about developing this?

Comment: You can do multiple DML statements in your controller, so you would insert your Recipient record first.  The record Id will be immediately available to you after the insert, so you can use it insert your related records.  See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm) for an example.

Comment: Thanks. However in creating a wizard it is multiple VF pages and instead I need all the fields to be on the same page - the insert in the class still works fine in a single page?

Comment: Yes.  Note that the example is still a single VF page even though there are various conditional sections on it.